# NSOperation and CoreData Threading

Tags: iphone, objective-c, multithreading, core-data

I'm passing some NSManagedObject data between two threads using NSOperationQueue with concurrency level to max of 1 and I'd like some suggestions on whether I'm doing this correctly.

Since NSManagedObject is not thread-safe, I'm sending in the NSManagedObjectID from ThreadA (main thread) to ThreadB via an NSOperation derived class. The general work flow:

> ThreadA (main thread):
>
> - creates NSPersistentStoreCoordinator
> - creates main NSManagedObjectContext(1)
> - creates NSManagedObjectContext(2) for use in workerThread
> - creates MyNSOperationItem, passes along NSManagedObjectContext and adds MyNSOperationItem to NSOperationQueue
>
> ThreadB (NSOperationQueue's thread):
>
> - NSOperation derived class will retrieve data from the persistent
>   store using the supplied objectID.

My NSOperation class looks like this:

```
@interface MyNSOperationItem: NSOperation
{
    // MyNSOperationItem is created in thread1 and MOC will be 
    // set on creation
    NSManagedObjectContext   *threadedMOC;
   
    NSManagedObjectID        *workItemObjectID;
}
@end
```

So is it okay for my NSOperation derived class to have a reference to NSManagedObjectContext or should I store the second NSManagedObjectContext elsewhere? Since this is a queue, numerous instances of MyNSOperationItem will have been created, each of them pointing to the same NSManagedObjectContext.

Answer (score 5):

I think this should give you all you need:

[http://developer.apple.com/mac/libra...reData/Articles/cdMultiThreading.html](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreData/Articles/cdMultiThreading.html)

If you need to offload the fetch to a background thread, here is a little tip from the document I referenced above:

> Fetching in a Background Thread
>
> One of the simplest multi-threading
>   techniques you can use with Core Data
>   to improve application responsiveness
>   is to execute a fetch request on a
>   background thread. (Note that this
>   technique is only useful if you are
>   using an SQLite store, since data from
>   binary and XML stores is read into
>   memory immediately on open.) This
>   means that if a fetch is complicated
>   or returns a large amount of data, you
>   can return control to the user and
>   display results as they arrive. For an
>   example of how to do this, see the
>   BackgroundFetching example in
>   /Developer/Examples/CoreData/.
>
> *You use two managed object contexts
>   associated with a single persistent
>   store coordinator. You fetch in one
>   managed object context on a background
>   thread, and pass the object IDs of the
>   fetched objects to another thread. In
>   the second thread (typically the
>   application's main thread, so that you
>   can then display the results), you use
>   the second context to fault in objects
>   with those object IDs (you use
>   objectWithID: to instantiate the
>   object).*

Comment: The link referenced a sample app called 'BackgroundFetching' in the '/Developer/Examples/CoreData' -- no such directory exists on my machine. Any ideas on where to find that sample?

Comment: Yep. You're right. And it doesn't appear to be available on the dev site any more either. Not sure what the deal is. You could file a documentation bug with Apple that points out the out of date information. Maybe they'll update it with a new path or link. Then again, maybe they'll update it and remove the path/link altogether. Sorry about that.